# Scala: Read a text file and filter on list of values

Tags: scala, filter, text-files

I want to read in a text file and filter lines that contain only certain values in a particular column.  So "if line 1, column 2 contains "Bob" or "Tom" or "Fred", then return that line.  The result would only contain lines where the second element of each line is either Bob, Tom, or Fred.

It thought this would work:

```
 val trans = io.Source.fromFile(inputFile).getLines.map(x => x.split("\11")).filter(line =>("Bob", "Tom", "Fred").contains.line(2)).toArray
```

but after looking at it, it doesn't really make sense that it would work (and it doesn;t).  I can do it with a single value like this:

```
val trans = io.Source.fromFile(inputFile).getLines.map(x => x.split("\11")).filter(line =>line(2) contains "Bob").toArray
```

but can't figure how do multiple values.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to check whether one column of a line—a *single string*—is contained in *a sequence* of strings:

```
val names = Seq("Bob", "Tom", "Fred")
```

Then your `filter` call becomes

```
...filter(line => names.contains(line(2)))
```

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I was close but not quite there.  Just for a little more info can you shed some light on why contains(line(2)) works but contains.line(2) does not?

Comment: The methods is `contains(elem: A)`. You cannot just omit the parenthesis and write a period, that's just illegal syntax. What would be allowed is _infix notation_: `filter(line => names contains line(2))`